# Compiling references in Texpad

Tags: bibliographies, texpad

I am using Texpad for the first time. I just imported my fully functional .tex and .bib file into it. Now I am having trouble compiling references in Texpad. 
This is the code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{mathrsfs,upref} 

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand{\blankbox}[2]{
%
  \parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering
   \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
      \fbox{\raisebox{0pt}[#2]{\hspace{#1}}}%
    }%
  }
  \begin{document}

  \nocite{*}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{knsref}




  \end{document} `
```

When I use the bib file named knsref.bib as

```
`@article{Menche2015,
  author  = {Menche, J. and Sharma, a. and Kitsak, M. and Ghiassian, S. D. 
             and Vidal, M. and Loscalzo, J. and a.-L. Barabasi},
  doi     = {10.1126/science.1257601},
  file    = {:Users/hannahcatabia/Desktop/ordovas\_project/papers/menche/201502-19\_Science-Incomplete.pdf:pdf},
  issn    = {0036-8075},
  journal = {Science},
  number  = {6224},
  pages   = {1257601--1257601},
  title   = {{Uncovering disease-disease relationships through the incomplete interactome}},
  url     = {http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/doi/10.1126/science.1257601},
  volume  = {347},
  year    = {2015},
}`

I get the following output pdf
```

[image]

But when I edit the bib file `knsref.bib` as

```
`@article{Menche2015,
  author  = {Menche, J. and Sharma, a. and Kitsak, M. and Ghiassian, S. D. 
             and Vidal, M. and Loscalzo, J. and a.-L. Barabasi},
  doi     = {10.1126/science.1257601},
  file    = {:Users/hannahcatabia/Desktop/ordovas\_project/papers/menche/201502-19\_Science-Incomplete.pdf:pdf},
  issn    = {0036-8075},
  journal = {Science},
  number  = {6224},
  pages   = {1257601--1257601},
  title   = {{Uncovering disease-disease relationships through the incomplete interactome}},
  url     = {http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/doi/10.1126/science.1257601},
  volume  = {347},
  year    = {2015},
}
@article {MR592387,
    AUTHOR = {Kowalski, S. and S\l odkowski, Z.},
     TITLE = {A characterization of multiplicative linear functionals in
              {B}anach algebras},
   JOURNAL = {Studia Math.},
  FJOURNAL = {Polska Akademia Nauk. Institut Matematyczny. Studia
              Mathematica},
    VOLUME = {67},
      YEAR = {1980},
    NUMBER = {3},
     PAGES = {215--223},
      ISSN = {0039-3223},
   MRCLASS = {46H05},
  MRNUMBER = {592387},
MRREVIEWER = {James C. S. Wong},
}
```

I get the output pdf as [image]

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Add relevant code as text, not as an image please.

Comment: Did you make sure to run the needed bibliography processor?

Comment: @Johannes_B the changes are made now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (bibliography not showing) with Texpad on iPhone/iPad. When I installed the Publishing Packages bundle, it started working, so my suggestion is to make sure you have the packages you need installed.

I'm not a huge fan of Texpad, but it seems to be the best solution for use with an iPhone/iPad, unless you SSH to a machine that runs emacs...